# Generate C# classes from JSON Schema

Tags: .net, wcf, json, jsonschema

I'm creating a C# WCF Web Service that return a lot of data in a JSON format.
The client is an iPad application that is currently being developped by another team, So I'm working on specifications, without example data.
Currently the JSON string is created by the .net framework, my Web Service is returning a C# object containing all the information that are then serialized by the framework using DataContracts.

My problem is that the communication specifications only contain JSON Schema files (based on http://json-schema.org/). In order to facilitate the development I'd like to generate the corresponding classes in C# but as the files contain quite a lot of information and there are a dozen of files, I don't really want to create those classes manually.

So I'm looking for a tool that would allow me either :

- To generate C# classes from a JSON Schema.
- To convert a JSON Schema to an XSD file. Then it would be easy to create the classes as there are plenty of tool to generate classes from XSD.

I found a lot of tools to validate a JSON string against a JSON Schema or to generate classes from the JSON string but nothing that seem to help me.
There is [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) but it seems to be a library and not a tool and I didn't found any information about generating classes with it.

So if anyone knows a tools or has an idea on how I could generate those classes (I tried a tool that create the classes in Java but I couldn't make it work).

Comment: This question is not exactly what I'm looking for. I don't have any JSON string, I just have a JSON Schema. 
There are tools for JSON string -> Class. But can't find one for JSON Schema -> Class.

Comment: I found this site, it's perfect for converting JSON Schemas to C#, enums, JsonConverters and all: https://quicktype.io/csharp/ . (Can't leave an answer as the question has been closed. It's a good question but there have been no complete answers.)

Comment: Thank you @MattD finally someone posted the right answer

Answer (score 60):

Visual Studio 2017 has this feature.

From the menu, choose Edit, Paste Special, Paste JSON As Classes. Paste in the JSON and Visual Studio will create the required classes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, its worked great for me, you saved my a lot of time :)

Comment: Doesn't work for a SCHEMA ... Just a JSON string

Comment: I has issues with JSON2CSHARP, but this answer worked perfectly

Comment: up voted for useful info. Yet, would be better to use schema since they specify optional/required properties, default values, etc. Those details are lost when generating the classes from data. So you could end up with something that is structurally correct, but that doesn't actually meet a required spec.

Comment: This might not be from a schema but it was exacly what i was looking for! thanks man!

Comment: Has to be from Schema, "sample" files are unlikely to have all of the possible permutations.  So disappointed that Visual Studio (or Code) have not provided this.

Comment: I dont see this in VS 2022

Comment: The question was how to generate class form json SCHEMA. Infer data types json content is inaccurate.

Answer (score 51):

Look up this library on nuget. The [NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration](http://njsonschema.org) can be used to generate C# or TypeScript code from a JSON schema:

```
var generator = new CSharpGenerator(schema);
var file = generator.GenerateFile();
```

The file variable now contains the C# code for all the classes defined in the JSON schema.

Comment: @rico-suter No one has ever explained properly how to load all reference schemas residing in a folder while generating code. Not a single example on any site till today.

Comment: This is now a correct URL to json2csharp converter tool https://json2csharp.com.

Comment: will also point out that you actually need to add at least two packages to make this work... NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration (which adds other pkgs like NJsonSchema) AND NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp.

Comment: The site doesn't translate json schema any more. Just json data. :-(

Comment: but does not support "onOf" a common Schema element...

Answer (score 9):

You can use the library [NJsonSchema](http://njsonschema.org) to read a JSON schema or generate one from a type, and generate a C# class from it.

If you need a GUI for these tasks, you can try the NSwagStudio GUI from the [NSwag](http://nswag.org) tools to do so... (it is also based on NJsonSchema)

Comment: You should disclosure that you're the actual developer

Comment: there is also visual json editor: https://github.com/rsuter/VisualJsonEditor

Answer (score 7):

In order to answer this correctly you need to know what version (draft) the Json Schema has.

Examples which libraries can handle which Schema (2018-01-19):

```
Json.NET Schema supports draft 3, draft 4, draft 6 (MIT)
Manatee.Json supports draft 4, draft 6, draft 7 (MIT)
NJsonSchema supports draft 4 (Ms-PL)
```

http://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-dotnet

With `NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration` you can't send the actual JSON in directly either, you first need to convert it to an actual schema (You will often get the error: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'NJsonSchema.JsonSchema4` otherwise).

Example with running code, `Schemas` folder located at project root:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(location, @"..\..\..\Schemas"));
        var schemaJson = File.ReadAllText($"{path}Test.json");
        var schema = JsonSchema4.FromJsonAsync(schemaJson).Result;
        var generator = new CSharpGenerator(schema);
        var generatedFile = generator.GenerateFile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> So I'm looking for a tool that would allow me either :
>      To generate C# classes from a JSON Schema...

I haven't used it myself so I can't comment too much about it, but it seems like the tool "[json-schema-to-poco](https://github.com/codedemonuk/json-schema-to-poco/)" would fit what you need.

Per its github readme:

> Converts JSON schema files into plain old CLR objects in C#.
>   Useful for running as part of an automated build process.

Comment: Unfortunately, json-schema-to-poco is just a stub without any real implementation

Answer (score 4):

Here is an online class generator that I've used in the past to generate C# classes from a sample set of JSON data:

http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: and also see http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

I had a need for this today and didn't see any solid answers to your question so I whipped this up.  It's not perfect but it's a good starting point to build off of.

https://gist.github.com/rushfrisby/c8f58f346548bf31e045

Comment: Nice one, yours is the first schema to code generator, and not example json to code gen I have found that actually works.

Comment: I have blatantly ripped off @rushonroeks code and split it out so i can gen other code/models - specifically Knockout view models : https://gist.github.com/RhysC/480e7a758639a3215701

Comment: Note that rushonerok's code relies on JSON.NET which hasn't yet been updated to support JsonSchema v4: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/115

Comment: if you're interest in adapting this code for v4 JNK wrote a library for it which can be found at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have a simple Json schema and it cannot translate it. I have not had such an issue with NJsonSchema. 
My schema: 
https://file.io/YQKnrB8gfgxa

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Help of Json.NET
There is a Json.Schema namespace that can be useful.

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

Json.NET - Quick Starts & API Documentation
Newtonsoft.Json.Schema Namespace
Namespaces ► Newtonsoft.Json.Schema

The project page: http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, but aside from building my own class generator (which I'll probably do if I don't find an existing tool), I don't think it can help me to generate those classes without too much effort.

Comment: @JulienN did you ever write your own class generator?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember but I don't think so, I probably didn't have the time, I would have published it if I did :). 3 years later, it still doesn't exist ?

Comment: @JulienN if it does exist, this question ranks higher on google. I'll keep searching, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Did anyone found any solution to this ? In my case even similar thing in JavaScript would do the job ?