# Deserializing Json Schema to Json String or Object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json schema and I need to convert it to a C# object or at least into json string.

is there any way to do it by code or by using some tool?

for the Json I'm currently using `Json.net`.

this is one of my schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "UserGroupWsDTO",
  "type": "object",
  "properties":
  {
    "members":
    {
      "type": "array",
      "items":
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties":
        {
          "uid":
          {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "uid":
    {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name":
    {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I need this to create an Object for deserialize the json

**EDIT**
My Json schema version is 4 and JSON Schema to POCO doesn't support it

Comment: Goto http://json2csharp.com/ and paste your json in there - all the classes will be created for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate C# classes from JSON Schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358745/generate-c-sharp-classes-from-json-schema)

Comment: i can't use json2csharp because i have a Json schema.

Comment: https://github.com/codedemonuk/json-schema-to-poco/

Comment: Old question I know bit did anyone find the answer for a v4 Json Schema .. Suggested answers are v3 or below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [JSON Schema to POCO](https://github.com/codedemonuk/json-schema-to-poco/) which supports v3 JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just "browsing" `key-values`, then you don't need any extra libs...

just do:

```
var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var dict = obj.First.First.Children().Cast<JProperty>()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p =>p.Value);

var dt =  (string)dict["title"];
```

but if instead you need an object of the string, then define a class and deserialize the string to that class... follow this example:

1st define the classes:

```
public class Uid
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Properties2
{
    public Uid uid { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Properties2 properties { get; set; }
}

public class Members
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Items items { get; set; }
}

public class Uid2
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public Members members { get; set; }
    public Uid2 uid { get; set; }
    public Name name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string __invalid_name__$schema { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}
```

---

and this is the implementation:

```
 string json = @"{...use your json string here   }";

    RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

    Console.WriteLine(root.title);
    // UserGroupWsDTO
```

Comment: I need an Object for deserialize the json

Comment: My problem is how to obtain a json, because otherwise for create the "Account" object i need to read the Json schema

Comment: @frenk91,new changes, so again please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: in arbitrary schemas you might need to resolve type references and so on