# How to Generate C# Objects classes from Json schema for .Net 4.5+

Tags: c#, .net, json

First off, i found this:

[Generate C# classes from JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358745/generate-c-sharp-classes-from-json-schema)

and although it seems to have the answer. It does not work in .net 4.5+.

I don't want to run compatibility in my application because its using a lot of new API functions.

My goal is to receive the Json, write to file the model.cs  and the rest of my application can use it. But is there a library, resource or method to do this for newer applications?

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Which of the answers did you try and how did they not work in .Net 4.5+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DangKhuong.JSONtoC
http://json2csharp.com/ 
https://github.com/ststeiger/json2csharp

or use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(json);
```